# Periodically copy files from internal to external SD card

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, file-management

How can I schedule moving camera directory from internal phone storage to external SD card?

I want to move new files in the directory every day, to free up space on internal storage.

Is there any way for this such as by using script? (I have a rooted device)

Comment: Did you consider any [tag:automation] app yet? [tag:Tasker] can do it easily. Cannot your Camera app be set to write into external SD card, or do you not want to explicitly set it like that?

Comment: Some apps do not allow saving files to external storage cards. On Linux I'd just write simple shell script and schedule cron job.

Comment: I do not have a Lollipop device which supports external SD card, else, I would've given a definite answer. But in Tasker you can use shell commands for sure.